# Looping for each worksheet across two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I want to basically run a for loop that looks like

```
for each worksheet in workbook1 and workbook2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up two loops

```vb
Dim WB As Variant, WS As Variant
For Each WB In Array(Workbook1, Workbook2)
    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
```